# How do I get feedback from T32 after running cmm scripts?

Tags: python, trace32, lauterbach

I am running  a T32 CMM script as below via command line(putting in a python wrapper) however I would like to know the status of T32 whether the script has been running successfully or was there an error,how can I that feedback from T32?

```
cd C:\T32\bin\windows64
```

Config.t32:

```
RCL=NETASSIST
PORT=20000
PACKLEN=1024

; Environment variables
OS=
ID=T32
TMP=C:\Users\jhigh\AppData\Local\Temp
SYS=C:\T32


PBI=
USB

; Printer settings 
PRINTER=WINDOWS
```

USAGE:-

```
t32marm.exe -s c:\Temp\vi_chip_cmd_line.cmm \\Filerlocation\data\files
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Should the TRACE32 application also quit when the script has finished? Or do you want to check the execution state of your script via the TRACE32 remote API?

Comment: Holger - Thanks for your response...it should not QUIT,want to check the execution state ,once finished the TRACE32 application will be in running state in a successful case

Answer (score 3):

The TRACE32 "API for Remote Control and JTAG Access" allows you to communicate with a running TRACE32 application.

To enable the API for your TRACE32 application, just add the following two lines to your TRACE32 start-configuration file ("config.t32"). Empty lines before and after the two lines are mandatory.

```
RCL=NETASSIST
PORT=20000
```

The usage of the API is described in the PDF api_remote.pdf, which is in the PDF folder of your TRACE32 installation or you can download it from http://www.lauterbach.com/manual.html

You can find examples on how to use the remote API with Python at http://www.lauterbach.com/scripts.html (Just search the page for "Python")

To check if your PRACTICE script ("vi_chip_cmd_line.cmm") is still running, use the API function *T32_GetPracticeState()*;

I also suggest to create an artificial variable in the beginning of your script with `Var.NEWGLOBAL int \state`. During your scripted test, set the variable "\state" to increasing values with `Var.Set \state=42`. Via the TRACE32 command `EVAL Var.VALUE(\state)` and API call *T32_EvalGet()* you can get the current value of the variable "\state" and by doing so, you can check, if your script reached its final state.

Another approach would be to write a log-file from your PRACTICE script  ("vi_chip_cmd_line.cmm") by using the TRACE32 command `APPEND` and read the log file from your Python script.

Comment: Few questions 1.I looked at the python scripts,I couldnt find one which uses `T32_GetPracticeState` 2.Can you explain `Var.Set \state=42` ,why do we have to use 42? I still have to try and see if I can incorporate and get going with what all you set

Comment: I hard coded the dll in the t32apicmd.py to use `t32api = r'C:\T32\demo\api\capi\dll\t32api.dll'`,I get the below error,how can I figure out the right dll to use and where can I get it? `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t32apicmd.py", line 152, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "t32apicmd.py", line 87, in main
    t32api.T32_Config(b"NODE=",node.encode('latin-1'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'T32_Config'
`

Comment: About 42: This was just an example. You can assign any numeric value. You can also change the variable's name. (It just has to start with a backslash)

Comment: ok thanks,how about the error?can you provide guidance on how to debug that and get rid of?

Comment: Well, if you have a 64-bit python binary on Windows you should use t32api64.dll for a 32-bit python binary on Windows you should use t32api.dll and for Linux use t32api64.so (or t32api.so in case of 32-bit python binary on Linux)

Comment: I can't help you with your particular error message. I suggest to contact the Lauterbach support, if you have problems to use the remote API.

Comment: I figured out the right dll and running the script throws the error`Connecting...
Failed once to initialize a remote connection with TRACE32 PowerView.
Failed twice to initialize a remote connection with TRACE32 PowerView.I updated the config.t32 to use the RCL and PORT... any idea why it is still not connecting?how to debug this?
`

Comment: Could there be an issue with your local firewall? Anyway: Use the command t32rem.exe to test, if you can communicate with your TRACE32 instance. You can find t32rem.exe usually at C:\t32\bin\windows or on our TRACE32 installation DVD. This DOS command line tool sends a TRACE32 command to your TRACE32 application. E.g. `t32rem localhost port=20000 version` should open the VERSION window inside TRACE32. If not, you have to check your config-file and or firewall/network settings. But if it works, the problem is somewhere in your python code or python framework.

Comment: I dont have a t32rem.exe ,I only see t32marm.exe,t32pbi.exe,t32start.exe,t32win.exe,trace32.api
I am on a windows7 machine and using t32api.dll,my firewall is off and I have a license....updated the question 
with screen shots..I run the script you provided..it throws no error neither it runs the command "AREA",
I am missing something very obvious....can I get remote support on this one?really appreciate if you point me to a person who can 
provide remote support

Comment: For "remote support" you should contact the Lauterbachs' technical support. For a suitable contact please go to  http://www.lauterbach.com/tsupport.html

Comment: You can download the complete TRACE32 software at http://www.lauterbach.com/download_trace32.html This will definitely include t32rem.exe

Answer (score 1):

Please check your T32 installation for a demo on how to use the T32 API (demo/api/python). Keep in mind that it will not work without a valid license. It's also important that if you use Python inside 32-bit cygwin on a 64-bit host you need to load the 32-bit DLL.

Configuration:

```
RCL=NETASSIST
PORT=20000
PACKLEN=1024
```

Python script:

```
import platform
import ctypes

# Adjust the path / name to the DLL
t32api = ctypes.CDLL("./t32api64.dll")

t32api.T32_Config(b"NODE=",b"localhost")
t32api.T32_Config(b"PORT=",b"20000")
t32api.T32_Config(b"PACKLEN=",b"1024")

t32api.T32_Init()
t32api.T32_Attach(1)
t32api.T32_Ping()

t32api.T32_Cmd(b"AREA")

t32api.T32_Exit()
```

Then you can use the commands / techniques that Holger has suggested:

```
T32_GetPracticeState()
```

to get the current run-state of PRACTICE. And / or set a variable inside your script

```
Var.Assign \state=1
Var.Assign \state=2
....
```

and then poll it using *T32_ReadVariableValue()*

Comment: dev15 - Thanks for your response...I dont have a t32rem.exe ,I only see t32marm.exe,t32pbi.exe,t32start.exe,t32win.exe,trace32.api
I am on a windows7 machine and using t32api.dll,my firewall is off and I have a license....updated the question 
with screen shots..I run the script you provided..it throws no error neither it runs the command "AREA",
I am missing something very obvious....can I get remote support on this one?really appreciate if you point me to a person who can 
provide remote support